# What is the tag “optical” used for and what is “optical-drive” used for?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-request, tag-synonyms

Aren't those two, [optical](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/optical) and [optical-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/optical-drive) the same?

If not, could somebody please add a text to both of them which explains the difference?

Comment: [optical] is a meta tag that could refer to optical drive, optical mouse, fiber optic connection, etc.  The tagged questions need cleanup.

Answer (score 4):

As [optical](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/optical) was only used on 9 questions I have gone ahead and removed it.

It was abused to be a modifier for several different things

- optical mice
- optical drives
- optical audio
- optical lenses in 3D modelling

As such it was a meta tag and deserved burnination.

Comment: Although it doesn't have questions any more, it still seems to exist. Compare http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/optical to http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/opticalasdfasdf

Comment: @moose   The tag will get cleaned up at the end of the day assuming it is not re-abused in the mean time. There is a script that runs in the night and silently kills dead tags.